# How to fill in a large right-angle gap at my front door frame?

Tags: walls, gap, front-door, filling

I recently had a new front door and frame [installed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/255061/should-i-be-disappointed-about-this-quality-of-craftsmanship-in-new-front-door) in my London Victorian house. However, rather than neatly filling the gap between the inside wall and the frame, they simply used a strip of beading/trim to cover the gap.

I did not want to have the strip of beading there, so I removed it. However, now I am left with a large right-angled gap to try to fill.

[image: Large gap between front door frame and wall.]

What would be a good way to fill this gap?

Originally, I intended to use some strips of wood to extend the wall and door frame into the corner, but one problem with this gap is that it varies in width, meaning I'd have to very carefully shape the wood to fit.

Is there a good way to fix this? Note that I really don't want to have a piece of beading there, I would like a perfect right-angled corner.

Also note, I will be painting over the wallpaper soon, so the new fill doesn't need to match the wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

The beading is the only practical way to cover that gap.
That said, since it is not an option for you, the other options involve an extensive amount of time and patience.
If that is within your guidelines, then you can either fill the gap with backer rod and expandable foam. Wait a day or so for it to dry. carefully and laboriously trim it flush with the wall and door frame. Making sure that you get a straight "perfect right-angled corner". Then fill the smaller gaps and holes with wood filler. Again sanding and being sure the corner is to your liking.
( this may take multiple tries and applications of filler.)
Finally skim the corner with drywall compound. Sand again to feather the edges and apply your paint.

OR; Your can cut fill the gap as above, letting it not fill the void completely. Trim wood to fit the gap. Use drywall compound or another type of mastic to adhere the wood to the filler material, being careful not to allow it to sink too deep.  Apply caulk to the edges being sure to get your "perfect right-angled corner". Then paint.
Both methods are labor intensive and take plenty of time for materials to dry before proceeding to the next step.  This is why the installers attached beading.      Good luck

Comment: Thanks RMDman, I think I'll try your second option. I bought some right-angled wood, and carefully measured the gap every 30cm, marked the wood accordingly, and cut it. It fits nicely. Next, I'll drill some holes in it, and glue the wood into position, then inject expanding foam through the holes to reinforce the back, then fill, sand and paint.